# Echo ACF subfield of group in element

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to output the inout from a subfield of a group in AFC.

With a regular textfield I just use:

```
 <?php $ups4 = get_field('ups_four', 'option'); ?>
   </a <?php echo $ups4; ?></a>
```

Which is simple enough, but I fail to do this with a subfield. I've tried to go through examples but nothing works.

The type group name is `header_usps` and the subfield name `usp_1`.

How do I echo the subfield in an element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try it like this (Not sure what exactly you were trying to achieve with the `<a>` tag, but it was broken, so I fixed that as well):

```
<?php $ups4 = get_field('header_usps_usp_1', 'option'); ?>
<a href="#"><?php echo $ups4; ?></a>
```